# Node.JS Event Emitter - Call On Method Internally

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, eventemitter

I am writing a program for my beaglebone black to control certain aspects of beer brewing process via a webpage. I am using socket.io to keep communications real-time. To do this, I am passing the socket object to actions located in the hardware classes. Some of the classes, such as my temp_sensor class use the eventEmitter pattern to allow other objects to subscribe to its data. However, when I use method of the temp_sensor to subscribe a passed in socket, it is telling me that the object (this) does not have a method "on". Below is my code:

```
module.exports = temp_sensor;

var fs = require("fs"),
    exec = require("child_process").exec,
util = require("util"),
EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var w1path = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/";


function temp_sensor(config){
// Put sensor verification code here//
this.name = config.name;
this.address = config.w1_address;
this.path = w1path + this.address + "/w1_slave";
this.value = null;
this.unit = config.unit;
this.emit_interval = 2000;
this.type = config.type;
this.subscribers = 0;
this.emitting = false;
this.prev_temp = null;
if (config.emit_interval){this.emit_interval = config.emit_interval;}
var self = this;
/*this.emit_data = setInterval(self.readSensor(function(temp) {
    if (temp !== this.prev_temp) {
        var timestamp = new Date().toJSON()
        var data = {
            "name": this.name,
            "temp":temp,
            "timestamp": timestamp
        };
        self.emit("temp_data", data);
        this.prev_temp = temp;
    };
}),this.emit_interval);*/
}

util.inherits(temp_sensor, EventEmitter);

temp_sensor.prototype.readSensor = function(callback){
var cmd = "cat " + this.path + " | grep t= | cut -f2 -d= | awk '{print $1/1000}'";
exec(cmd , function( error, stdout, stderr ) {
    if (error) { callback(error); }
    callback( Math.round((parseFloat(stdout) * 1.8 + 32) * 10) / 10 );
});
};



// component actions
temp_sensor.prototype.actions = [];

temp_sensor.prototype.actions["subscribe"] = function(socket) {
this.subscribers++;
this.on("temp_data",function(data) {
    socket.emit("temp_sensor",data);
});
};

temp_sensor.prototype.actions["unsubscribe"] = function(socket) {
this.subscribers--;
// remove listener
};
```

I am getting this error:

/var/lib/cloud9/brewbone/lib/temp_sensor.js:64
        this.on("temp_data",function(data) {
             ^
TypeError: Object  has no method 'on'
    at Array.temp_sensor.actions.subscribe (/var/lib/cloud9/brewbone/lib/temp_sensor.js:64:7)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, the commented out this.emit_data is giving me the following error (which is why it is commented out for now): timers.js:234
    callback.apply(timer, args);
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Timer.exports.setInterval.timer.ontimeout (timers.js:234:14)
Any help on this would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is that you inherit *EventEmitter* in *temp_sensor*. And the method *on* is actually available in the prototype of *temp_sensor*. But later you create another object which has its own prototype - *actions["subscribe"]*. So, the *this* here:

```
temp_sensor.prototype.actions["subscribe"] = function(socket) {
   this.subscribers++;
   this.on("temp_data",function(data) {
      socket.emit("temp_sensor",data);
   });
};
```

points to something else.

I'll suggest to leave the prototype and try implementing the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even catch that I was using a different object. For now, I am passing in the component into the action so that I can act on it. I will look further into the revealing module pattern. Thanks!